# Twitter Feed JS works with Firefox & Chrome but not in IE. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, browser, twitter, internet-explorer-8

The following code works perfectly in both Firefox and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> 
<head> 
<meta charset=UTF-8 />

<title>Twitter Test</title>

<script src="http://twitterjs.googlecode.com/files/twitterjs-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
getTwitters('twitter', { 
  id: 'glasgow', 
  count: 1, 
  enableLinks: true, 
  ignoreReplies: true, 
  clearContents: true,
  timeout:100,
  template: '<div class="tweet"><p>%text%</p></div>'
});
</script>

</head> 

  <body>

     <div id="twitter"></div>   

  </body> 

</html>
```

It shows my Twitter feed test in FF & C, but not IE8.

Is there an obvious reason for this?

Many thanks

Comment: Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/p8yN6/ IE9's console says `SCRIPT5009: 'twitterlib' is undefined twitterjs-2.0.0.min.js, line 10 character 1305` and `SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/remy/twitterlib/master/twitterlib.min.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch 
`.

Comment: Many many thanks for the speedy response. 'jsfiddle' appears to be timing out right now but I will keep an eye on it over the next few minutes.

Comment: I have checked the JSFiddle link in IE, but the Result frame is blank. Again it loads fine in Firefox and Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Issue resolved :) See the yellow "alert" on this page: http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved :) See the yellow "alert" on this page: remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step